# OrientDB-NET.binary - Saving Emoji not working

Tags: c#, serialization, orientdb, binary-serialization

I'm trying to save text that contains items such as emoji's, e.g. :point_right:. I can save the same text directly in the management UI. So I don't think that it is a database configuration issue, its currently set to UTF8 which is correct AFAIK. I believe that the issue is around the area where the string is serialized to binary for transport across the wire.

Thanks in Advance
Darren